# How to bypass wordpress are you sure you want to logout message woocommerce, and logout to hompage?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have an upper navigation menu with a logout link, when I click it first a message pops up asking me if I'm sure I want to log out. How do I bypass this message, remove it completely have logout automatically to the homepage? What link can I put in the logout menu link?

Currently it is this: http://website.com/my-account/customer-logout/

Comment: This is a duplicate: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/67336/how-to-log-out-without-confirmation-do-you-really-want-to-log-out

Comment: Further, you haven't shown how you are crafting the URL to log out.  If you are manually adding it to your Nav Menu, then you won't be able to use the answer below.

Answer (score 1):

This maybe happens because you are forgetting the neccessary nonce in the URL, which is being checked in wp-login.php:

```
case 'logout' :
check_admin_referer('log-out');
...
```

You should use wp_logout_url in order to retreive the URL including the nonce. If you want to redirect to a custom URL, simply pass it as an argument:

```
<a href="<?php echo wp_logout_url('/redirect/url/goes/here') ?>">Log out</a>
```

Another thing, you may also use wp_loginout which generates the link for you including translation:

```
echo wp_loginout('/redirect/url/goes/here');
```

That´s it.
Best regards.

Comment: Since the OP suggests they are probably adding this manually to their nav menu (not via code), you might address that issue as well in your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Since duplicates are permitted from one site to another, I'm posting this answer based on the original work here: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/156261/11704

Based on your question, it sounds like you want a `Log Out` link to appear in your nav menu.

In order to do that, and for that link to contain the proper NONCE (which is missing in your case, and is why the "Are you sure you want to log out?" message appears), you'll need to create a plugin or modify your theme.

Add the below code to your custom plugin file, or your theme's `functions.php` file:

```
// hook into WP filter for nav items
add_filter( 'wp_nav_menu_items', 'my_loginout_menu_link', 10, 2 );

// modify links in nav menu
function my_log_in_out_menu_link( $items, $args ) {
   // only do this if it's the "main" navigation
   if ( $args->theme_location == 'primary' ) {
      // if the user is logged in, add a log out link
      if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
         // use the official WP code to get the logout URL.
         // passed-in argument will cause it redirect to home page
         $items .= '<li class="log-out"><a href="'. wp_logout_url( home_url( '/' ) ) .'">'. __("Log Out", "your_themes_i18n_slug" ) .'</a></li>';
      } else {
      // if the user is NOT logged in, add a log in link
         $items .= '<li class="log-in"><a href="'. wp_login_url( get_permalink() ) .'">'. __( "Log In", "your_themes_i18n_slug" ) .'</a></li>';
      }
   }

   return $items;
}
```